# Gsuite Basic trial just ended today, but my email quota sent via Apps Script is still 100, why is that?

Tags: google-apps-script

Gsuite Basic trial just ended today, but my email quota sent via Apps Script is still 100, why is that? Upon reading some google documentations I am expecting it to increase to 1500 email sent per day.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#note1), you will have to wait for one or more billing cycles, depending on the number of users in your domain:

> Newly created G Suite domains are subject to the consumer limit for the first billing cycle if they have six or more users, or several billing cycles if they have fewer users. For more information, see the Help Center page on [sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852).

#### Reference:

- [Quotas for Google Services: Current quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas)